# Using Next.js middleware and withAuth breaks Playwright E2E tests with Prisma adapter in Github actions only

Tags: github-actions, prisma, playwright, next-auth

I already created a [discussion in the next-auth Github repository](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/9854), but I'm also sharing here in order to have more help :D

Here is the issue...

I'm working in a [personal open-source project](https://github.com/product-makers-hub/open-micro-saas) using next-auth as part of the tech stack.

The issue that I have is that if I add a middleware using the `withAuth` from next-auth, my tests are failing in Github actions only (in local everything is fine).

Here is when I had the test errors:

- [Commit change](https://github.com/product-makers-hub/open-micro-saas/commit/054d10f9b91ee33d06040ddce5efc6b10aa3b4aa).
- [GA log errors](https://github.com/product-makers-hub/open-micro-saas/actions/runs/7676361402/job/20987085300).

The middleware with withAuth:

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { authConfig } from "./config";
import { ADMIN_ROLE_NAME } from "./consts/roles-consts";

const adminRoutes = [
  "/admin",
  "/admin/dashboard",
  "/admin/dashboard/user-management",
];

export default withAuth(
  // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
  function middleware(req) {
    const isAdminRoute = adminRoutes.includes(req.nextUrl.pathname);

    const isUserAdmin =
      (req.nextauth.token?.role as any)?.name === ADMIN_ROLE_NAME;

    if (isAdminRoute && !isUserAdmin) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        new URL(authConfig.normalUserCallbackUrl, req.url),
      );
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => {
        return token?.isActive as any;
      },
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: authConfig.loginUrl,
    },
  },
);

/**
 * The config for the middleware, it needs to be static.
 * Therefore, it's not possible to use variables like adminRoutes array
 */
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/admin/",
    "/admin/dashboard",
    "/admin/dashboard/user-management",
    "/profile",
    "/dashboard",
  ],
};
```

I downloaded the Playwright html report and after debugging and some checks, I found out that in the test, it's behaving like the DB is empty (which is weird since there are another tests where the user is required to be authenticated).

[This SS](https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/10777626/300661817-36ce93f8-e337-4124-9edb-96719d7b2901.png?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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._6yC4xD7pv6lJhJJu4r5RfAMPHTZGhdoFerrxoWnUmA) is how the UI looks like when I'm getting the users from the DB, but in this case, behaves like there are not users (but I have an user logged in in the app).

As proof, I reverted the middleware and it's working as expected.

[This is how it looks like when is working](https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/10777626/300662422-887fa22d-789b-40bd-977c-68ad248cfe30.png?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.UmLzl_onDNDVKKTXhkVaW5PPPLg2aWO0ph77oGkC_oM).

- [Commit change without the middleware](https://github.com/product-makers-hub/open-micro-saas/commit/d491c2f6d29a9a7286ba360f8d48aa716372bae9).
- [GA log without error](https://github.com/product-makers-hub/open-micro-saas/actions/runs/7702822283/job/20991907683).

**The curious part is that Prisma is not returning data from the DB when the tests are failing, as if the DB does not have data in the users table.**

And if I just use the Next.js middlware with a simple console log (without the `withAuth` wrapper from next-auth), the tests are passing:

- [Commit with Next.js middleware without the `withAuth` that is passing](https://github.com/product-makers-hub/open-micro-saas/commit/401372ad21fbde7fe78dcab426adbc70f7d2a0a5).

What does this means?

If I use the `withAuth`, my tests fail, and if I don't, my tests pass. That's why I believe is a possible issue with `withAuth` middleware.

My first guess was that I was doing something wrong in my tests or I was missing something in the GA configurations, but is weird that only when I add a middleware I have the error and without the middleware I'm not having it, isn't?

I would appreciate any help or suggest